# Способы создания гибкого ПО

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, такая проблема:
У меня есть семейство классов, очень близких по смыслу.

Например, 1 класс имеет переопределенный метод базового класса, который чуть чуть отличается логикой. Другой класс так же в некоторых местах так же немного отличается. Когда мне нужно описать новую логику, которая снова чуть чуть отличается, то я снова вынужден делать новый класс, где теперь нужно проделать какую-то логику перед базовым алгоритмом.

Я чувствую, что можно пойти иным путем, что бы не плодить лишние сущности.

И вот я думаю, а можно все переделать таким образом, что бы можно на базе XML всем рулить или рано или поздно я во что-то упрусь и придется опять плодить похожие классы? Какие есть еще решения?

Comment: Интерфейсы и абстрактные классы решают множество задач где имеется семейство классов объединённых общей логикой.

Comment: Шаблонный метод. Отличающиеся части алгоритма вынести в виртуальные методы

Answer (score 4):

*Давным-давно я слушал курс "Устойчивость систем". На одном из занятий, профессор, пожилой мужик с PhD из лондонского University College, спросил: "Как Гурвиц открыл свой критерий устойчивости?" Все задумчиво помолчали. И тогда он ответил: "Through hard thinking (Путем упорных размышлений)." (Это о способах создания гибкого ПО.)*

То, что Вы описываете, это случай использования наследования ведущий к возникновению большой иерархии с короткими ответвлениями от основного узла или ствола. Такую иерархию можно значительно сжать/упростить, если вынести базовую и "чуть-чуть" отличающиеся логики в отдельный набор классов (а то и методов), которые передаются первоначальным классам (как параметры конструктора или как свойства).

При чем тут XML не совсем понятно, если только Ваши отличия в логике виртуальных методов не могут быть описаны конфигурационно.

Comment: Похоже, Вы говорите о паттерне проектирования "Стратегия".
Я тоже подумал посоветовать подобное :) Благо, что во многих случаях C# позволяет реализовать "Стратегию" лямбдой вместо создания отдельного класса